# Render XPDF forms into Laravel PHP Web Page

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, adobe, xpdf

I'm seeking guidance on the integration of XPDF into my Laravel project for rendering a specific PDF file. This PDF file can only be viewed in Adobe Acrobat Reader due to its advanced XPDF form features. My objective is to present this PDF within my web application, allowing users to input data and then giving them the option to save the completed PDF. How can I go about achieving this?

As an example, I have a PDF file like the one found on Google at this link: https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/migration/ircc/english/pdf/kits/forms/imm0008enu_2d.pdf. This particular PDF is not visible in Chrome or within an iframe, and it can only be opened in Adobe Acrobat Reader.

Comment: The PDF viewer plugin provided by Adobe themselves is not compatible with most modern web browsers any more, https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/display-pdf-in-browser.html Unless you find a different alternative (doubt it), your users will probably have to download the PDF, and open it in their locally installed Adobe Reader then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be understandably confused.

Files that are HYBRID.PDF are a mix of XML/XMP with a PDF cover sheet(s) that explains

> your PDF viewer may not be able to display **this type of document.**
> You can upgrade to the latest version of Adobe Reader for Windows®, Mac, or Linux® by
> visiting  http://www.adobe.com/go/reader_download.

So **XPDF also cannot view such files** as they are NOT ISO Open standards PDF.

> there's no PDF content in the file, other than that message you're seeing. All of the real content is in XFA format.
> Xpdf doesn't currently include an XFA renderer. I'm working on code for that, but I don't have an ETA right now.

[image]

IMHO dont wait, since the XFA format is considered redundant and highly problematic to work with without using Adobe Products. see https://www.datalogics.com/access-xfa-forms-with-forms-flattener

Even web browsers that see contents cannot show much or even if they can either mess up pages (especially how many) or are otherwise unable to process data.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Adobe allocated the .PDF extension to many types of file format, for `autoPDF` loading.

Such files are proprietary Adobe Live Cycle files, with a .PDF extension for compatibility **usage with Adobe PDF readers** and require specific Acrobat Readers for each platform.

The Page misleads by saying get Acrobat Linux as that was abandoned so long ago it cannot read these forms.

Even the Mac Acrobat Reader I understand MUST be **specifically only one 2014 version 11.0.09** or something like that? https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/ReleaseNotes/11/11.0.09.html see https://ircc.canada.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=660&top=18

And as for mobile or other users without a Super Windows X64 with vast Cash of Rams forget even attempting using Acrobat Windows for opening such forms.